# How can you change the default command to all commits in git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

When you execute the command git `rebase -i anotherBranch` the todo-list will appear with all commits marked as pick.

Is there a way to use, say, edit in all the commits by default instead of `pick`? I know is not hard to use replaceAll in your editor, but I wonder if there is a way to do this by default.

Or even better, instead to open the default text editor showing you all commits marked as "edit", to directly execute rebase as if all the commits were marked as "edit" without opening your editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the git config docs for sequence.editor,

```
git -c sequence.editor='sed -i s/pick/edit/' rebase -i anotherBranch
```

or

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i s/pick/edit/' git rebase -i anotherBranch
```

is what you want.

Comment: This is great! However, is there a way to give that editor a name and use it like difftool or mergetool? Something like "rebasetool". (You configure the tool with git config rebase.tool=myTool ; git config rebasetool.myTool.cmd='sed -i s/pick/edit/')

Comment: This way you could have one editor for 'edit' and other for 'squash' or passing parameters to your rebasetool to specify which one you want.

Comment: You could simply use an alias, e.g.: `ri = "f() { cmd=$1; shift; git -c sequence.editor=\"sed -i s/pick/$cmd/\" rebase -i \"$@\"; }; f"` and then use it as `git ri edit anotherBranch`.

Comment: @alfunx `!f()` not `f()`, git alias syntax uses the conventional `!` for shell invocation, but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do should be done using `git filter-branch`.

`git filter-branch` allow you to "move" over all your commits and then do whatever you wish to do. using `filter-branch` you can edit your commits with `--amend` or any other operation you wish to do

```
# use the --index-filter instead of the --tree-filter for better performance
git filter-branch --index-filter
```

Comment: I'm reading the docs and in the --index-filter option says that "is similar to the tree filter but does not check out the tree, which makes it much faster". I think your comment before the command is wrong.

Comment: You are right, I meant the opposite, Thanks for the notice. Index does not check out files while tree does.